# Optimize a logic which is dependent on whole data frame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have got some code which is taking a lot of time for obvious reasons. If anybody of you could guide me to optimize the code then it would be very helpful

```
def calculate_average(data, n_days):
    average_X = []
    for index, row in data.iterrows():
        y = row['Y']
        z = row['Z']
        end_date = row['Date']
        start_date = end_date - datetime.timedelta(n_days)
        sub_data = data[(data['Y']!=y) & (data['Z']==z) & (data['Date'].between(start_date, end_date))]
        average_X.append(sub_data['X'].mean())
    return average_X
```

**Edited:**

Here is code to get sample dataframe

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'X':[1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3], 'Y':['Y1', 'Y2', 'Y3', 'Y4', 'Y5', 'Y6', 'Y7', 'Y8'],
                'Z': ['XYZ', 'LKN', 'LKN', 'LKN', 'XYZ', 'TTT', 'XYZ', 'TTT'],
                'Date':pd.date_range(start='1/1/2018', end='1/08/2018')})
```

[image]

- X - Needs its average over selected data
- Y - Unique ID
- Z - ID but not unique
- Date - Simply date range, not unique

Comment: can you post your sample data frame with the intended output? that would be really helpful

Comment: @Datanovice I have edited post. Please have a look

Comment: Whenever you iterate over a DataFrame, 99.9% of the time you are doing it wrong. DataFrame is meant to be processed as an object.

Comment: @volcano I agree but I couldn't get my hands on any other way to get results. If you can help then would be very great. I have used `apply` but not sure if that can be utilized here